# Sync all Sharepoint file metadata via Webservices

Tags: web-services, api, sharepoint

I am looking to develop a Java-based Application that will talk to Sharepoint Webservices. The challenge is to fetch all the metadata for the Sharepoint files.
The metadata should include - Author, tags, comments etc as well acccess controls, groups etc.

Which APIs can i use to fetch all this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the [GetListItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems%28v=office.12%29.aspx) WebService.

Answer (score 0):

The one problem with your plan is that item level security information is not exposed via the out of the box provided web services.  If you want that you will have to write and deploy your own web service to the SharePoint servers.